# Neo4j Cypher match () in java. Find connected nodes

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have the follwing structure

```
        firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
        firstNode.setProperty( "person", "Andy " ); 
        Label myLabel = DynamicLabel.label("A");
        firstNode.addLabel(myLabel);
        secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
        secondNode.setProperty( "person", "Bobby" );
        Label myLabel1 = DynamicLabel.label("B");
        secondNode.addLabel(myLabel1);
        ThirdNode = graphDb.createNode();
        ThirdNode.setProperty( "person", "Chris " );
        Label myLabel2 = DynamicLabel.label("C");
        ThirdNode.addLabel(myLabel2);....

        relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( secondNode, RelTypes.emails );
        relationship.setProperty( "relationship", "email " );
        relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( ThirdNode, RelTypes.emails );
        relationship.setProperty( "relationship", "email " );
        relationship = secondNode.createRelationshipTo( ThirdNode, RelTypes.emails );
        relationship.setProperty( "relationship", "email " );
        relationship = secondNode.createRelationshipTo( FourthNode, RelTypes.emails );
        relationship.setProperty( "relationship", "email " );
```

firstNode is linked to second and third by the relation "emails". Similarly, second node is connected to third, fourth, first.

I want for each node output  somethinglike this:  secondNode=[firstNode, FouthNode, ThirdNode], firstNode=[second, third], third=...

I tried something like this:

```
try{
        ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
        ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("MATCH (secondNode{person:'Bobby'})<-[:emails]-(node)RETURN node");

        System.out.println(result.dumpToString());
        tx1.success();
    }
```

I got the output :`Node[0]{person:"Andy "}`

Im am very new to cypher. How to write match statement for this? Is this possible?

Comment: Don't create a new execution-engine use graphDb.execute !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your label should be something like :Person  not :A, :B, :C
- You want to aggregate by your first node.
- You should use uppercase re-types

try something like this:

```
MATCH (sender:Person)-[:EMAILS]->(receiver) 
RETURN sender,collect(receiver) as receivers
```

Comment: Thanks. perfect! it worked. But I did not specify direction.

Comment: I have posed a follow up question based on this. Could you please check that ? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693776/collecting-the-result-of-cypher-query-into-a-hash-map-java)