# Collecting the result of cypher query into a hash map java?

Tags: java, neo4j, hashmap, cypher

This is a followup of  [Finding connected nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677104/neo4j-cypher-match-in-java-find-connected-nodes) question.

The code is

```
    firstNode = graphDb.createNode();//creating nodes
    firstNode.setProperty( "person", "Andy " ); 
    Label myLabel = DynamicLabel.label("person");
    firstNode.addLabel(myLabel); ...

    relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( secondNode, RelTypes.emails );// creating relationships
    relationship.setProperty( "relationship", "email " );....


    ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
        ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("MATCH (sender:person)-[:emails]- (receiver)RETURN sender,  count(receiver)as count, collect(receiver) as receivers ORDER BY count DESC ");
        System.out.println(result.dumpToString());
```

The result I got was:

```
 sender                  | count | receivers                                                                 
Node[2]{person:"Chris"} | 3     | [Node[4]{person:"Elsa "},Node[0]{person:"Andy "},Node[1]{person:"Bobby"}] 
Node[4]{person:"Elsa "} | 3     | [Node[5]{person:"Frank"},Node[2]{person:"Chris"},Node[3]{person:"David"}]
Node[1]{person:"Bobby"} | 3     | [Node[2]{person:"Chris"},Node[3]{person:"David"},Node[0]{person:"Andy "}]
Node[5]{person:"Frank"} | 2     | [Node[3]{person:"David"},Node[4]{person:"Elsa "}
```

How to collect the sender as key and receivers as values? 
For ex : `{Frank =[David, Elsa],  Chris =[Elsa, Andy, Nobby]..`

Any idea?

Initially I tried  iterating something like this

```
        for (Map<String,Object> row : result) {
               Node x = (Node)row.get("receivers");
               System.out.println(x);

               for (String prop : x.getPropertyKeys()) {
                  System.out.println(prop +": "+x.getProperty(prop));

               }
```

This throws classcast exception. It works for column "sender" and not for "receivers".

I am very new to cypher. I don't know how to transform the result into a hash map. How is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the cypher to return a map instead... (split for readability)

```
MATCH (sender:person)-[:emails]->(receiver)
WITH sender, collect(receiver.person) as receivers
RETURN {sender: sender.person,  receivers: receivers)
ORDER BY size(receivers) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The above code throws error.  I don't want the result as map only in appearance. But the structure itself should be of the map form. Because If I want to get value of particular key , for ex result.get(2) does not return the values of second key. I guess I need  something like map.put(sender, receiver)

Answer (score 0):

The result can be treated as a list of maps, each map represents the key-value mapping of its record in the result.

Code to achieve this:

```
private List<Map<String, Object>> buildResultsList(Result result) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = new LinkedList<>();
        while (result.hasNext()) {
            Record record = result.next();
            results.add(record.asMap());
        }
        return results;
    }
```